# Default argument with *args

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop, arguments

I am new to python and currently learning about functions in python
I created a function which takes all type of argument (normal, *args, default argument, **kwargs)

```
def func (a, *args, b=3, **kwargs):
print(a) 
print(args) 
print(b) 
print(kwargs)
```

And to call the fuction i used

```
func (1, 3,5,4, 5, a=5,j=6)
```

But default argument value remains same and i don't know how to pass a different value to default parameter 'b'

How can i pass new values to default parameter 'b' in above function??

Answer (score 0):

The parameter *args is your issue.

The special syntax *args in function definitions in python is used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function. It is used to pass a non-key worded, variable-length argument list.

So *args takes all the parameters (since it expects a variable-length list), and b will never receive them. You need to remove *args.